# Student classification with Multinomial Logit

Tags: r, regression, classification, logit, multinomial-logit

I’m analyzing student performance data. In my dataset each row corresponds to a student and each column contains several performance metrics (continuous) and the student type (categorical, 4 types). The student type was computed in another analysis using Expectation-Maximization. This analysis based on how students were graded over time. I only have a small sample of 50 students.

I want to understand what characterizes each student type, regarding the performance features I have. I want to understand things like *“the more grade they have the more likely is to belong to a particular cluster”* and so on, if they are present at all in my data.

I have three questions:

1. I believe that what I need is **Multinomial Logistic Regression**. Am I right or is there a better way to achieve this?

   If yes, I’ve been exploring **Multinomial Logistic Regression** in `R`, using the `multinom` of the `nnet` package, but I need help with the following:
2. Understanding if the model has a good fit. So far I have the percentage of correctly classified instances, but I know this is not a very good measure of fit.
3. How to assess how good each individual predictor is. I know how to look for the exponentiated $\beta$, but I don’t know how to assess its significance. I read that using the t-distribution to compute the p-value here is usually a mistake. I found a [similar post here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63222/getting-p-values-for-multinorm-in-r-nnet-package), but a clear answer was not provided.

Comment: I believe [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/626216/247274) addresses how to evaluate the performance.